# How to have a condition for with-items as a whole, not for the individual items

Tags: ansible

I have this:

```
- name: Add hosts to /etc/hosts
  lineinfile:
    dest=/etc/hosts
    line='{{ item.dest }} {{ item.src }}'
    regexp='.*{{ item.src }}.*'
    state=present
  with_items:
    - "{{ hosts[service_name] }}"
  when: (service_name in hosts)
```

What I get

```
'dict object' has no attribute u'blah'
```

What I need is to skip the whole task if the when condition is false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to attach `when` condition to a whole task when using `with_items`.

But you can go another way – default iterator to empty list if there is no key, like this:

```
- name: Add hosts to /etc/hosts
  lineinfile:
    dest=/etc/hosts
    line='{{ item.dest }} {{ item.src }}'
    regexp='.*{{ item.src }}.*'
    state=present
  with_items: "{{ hosts[service_name] | default([]) }}"
```

In this case the task will have zero items to iterate over if you provide unknown service name.
Also note that I removed unnecessary list definition in your `with_items` construction.